# why to use "var" inside for in loop?

Tags: javascript, for-loop

This seems to be easy question, but I can't find an answer for this..

For example if I have the following object:

```
  var a = {
    foo : "FOO",
    bar : "BAR"
  }
```

Now, if I want to list properties of the objec, I should do the following :

```
  for( var b in a ) {
    // do something
  }
```

or, I can do this :

```
  for( b in a ) {
    // do something
  }
```

But, **which is the difference beetween these methods? Why to use "var" or why not to use "var" in for in loop?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you use a variable that has not been declared before without prepending `var`, you create a global variable.

```
function scope() {
    a = "hi";      // global
    var b = "ho";  // local
}
```

---

However, there is no difference between

```
for (var b in a) { /* .. */ }
```

and

```
var b;
for (b in a) { /* .. */ }
```

Answer (score 3):

Without var, `b` becomes global, and would then be able to interact with another definition of `b` which could lead to errors or unexpected behavior.

For example,

```
function example1(){
 for( b in a ){
  example2();
  //now when b comes back, it will reference the last item from example2,
  //essentially skipping the entire interior of a.
 }
}

function example2(){
 for( b in a ){
  //access a[b]
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't type `var` you would be declaring a global variable, so if you don't intend to use it later it wouldn't make sense, you'd be consuming memory without needing it